# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in obj_msgSend isKindOfClass:

Tags: objective-c, ios, gdb, exc-bad-access

I am getting a crash the second time I attempt to add a certain view as a subview.  The crash happens here:

```
-(void)AddAsScrollableSubContext:(UIView*)view {
    [pExtendedScrollableSubContextBounds addSubview: view]; //CRASH HERE
    pSubScroll.userInteractionEnabled = true;
}
```

the second time I call...

```
[mSongContext AddAsScrollableSubContext:pEQRoot];
```

The flow is something along the lines of

```
[mSongContext AddAsScrollableSubContext:pEQRoot];
...Load a lot of stuff
...Press a Button
...Unload a lot of stuff
[pEQRoot removeFromSuperview];
...Press a Button
[mSongContext AddAsScrollableSubContext:pEQRoot];
```

When I get the bad access the callstack looks like the following:
[image: Callstack]

Both objects (pExtendedScrollableSubContextBounds and pEQRoot) appear to be valid.  Adding other subview to pExtendedScrollableSubContextBounds works fine and calling other operations on pEQRoot (subview, frame) also work.

I read the in objsend r0 was the object and r1 was the selector so I looked at the memory address for r1 and saw...

[image: memdump]

This feels like I am trashing memory somewhere around isKindOfClass: but I am not quite sure.  Could anyone point me to more info on iOS obj_msgsend?  is there a way I can setup a watch point to catch when this memory trash is occurring?

Comment: This almost ALWAYS is a zombie object problem. Enable NSZombies and try again.

Comment: When you 'Unload a lot of stuff', do you release the mSongContext? Or between the first and second call?

Comment: My poorly named mSongContext is a global

Comment: Enabling zombies did fix the problem, Thanks.  Make it an answer if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NSZombies to fix the problem.

On a slightly unrelated note, there's a rule of thumb - NARC which stands for new, allocate, retain, copy. If a method call includes any of these keywords, then we have ownership of the object and we are then supposed to release the object.